# Calculation power of number in themselves with loops

Tags: c#

I'm new to C# and I'm trying to calculate power of (1,3) to themselves with loops but this code just calculate their squares I appreciate if someone helps me.

```
        for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
        {
            tav =i*i;
            Console.Write(tav);
        }
```

Comment: The trivial solution is to use `Math.Pow` instead of `*`, but it's more instructive to think about how you would implement this yourself with just multiplication and loops. My suggestion is the following: (1) Use Math.Pow to solve the problem, (2) try to replace Math.Pow with your own method which does the same, (3) integrate your method's code into your original method. You should now have the solution you are looking for.

Comment: 1, 2*2, 3*3*3, 4*4*4*4 - do you see the pattern? You need the number as the upper limit to a loop (how many times it will be multiplied) as well as being the starting number.

Comment: Think about how you would do this with a calculator.  Say your wanted 4^4 (i.e., 4x4x4x4).  You'd start with 4, then multiply it by 4 (getting 16).  Then you'd take the result and multiply it by 4 (getting 64) and then take that result and multiply it by 4 again (getting 256).  You need a variable with the current result in your loop.  Notice that no one is giving you an answer.  The idea if for you to read the comments and come up with something on your own

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
{
    int num = i;
    int result = num;
    for (int k = 2; k <= num; k++) { result *= num; }

    Console.WriteLine("{0}^{0} = {1}", num, result);
}
```